# Electron Snap file is not build after running command

Tags: packaging, snap, electron

https://gist.github.com/popey/7803cfbda9b337fab792c403e50e4709
Im following this tutorial.
After running `npm run dist` terminal outputs `missing script: dist`
After running `npm run lint` since it is mentionned in the tutorial to run the appropriate script which is listed in the scripts section in the `package.json` file, terminal output was `Finished 'lint' after 1.41 s`
. it is mentionned in the tutorial that the snap should have been built, but it seems that it has not.
i need help for that.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because the package you want to build (NDM) has no `dist` script in "scripts" in package.json file. I think that you can use `npm run build`, it should do the same thing.

You can learn more about package.json file from here: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json. It’s a npm thing, not directly related to snaps.

If you will encounter more problems, please, tell me.